# Json.net reading serialized array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to read JSON data from web, and i am using Json.net library for this task, the problem is if  there is only one json object

```
{"id":"2340","time":"2014-10-29 16:26:49"}
```

everything works fine, but if there is an array of them

```
[{"id":"2340","time":"2014-10-29 16:26:49"}, {"id":"2341","time":"2014-10-29 16:27:21"}]
```

Program isn't working.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

    namespace Localhostnet
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString('http://localhost/json.php');
                    LocalhostTiming jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LocalhostTiming>(htmlCode);
                    string timeId = jsonResponse.id;

                    MessageBox.Show(timeId);
                }
            }
        }

        public class LocalhostTiming
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string time { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

I've tried to add

```
public class DataContainer
{
    public List<LocalhostTiming> LocalhostTiming{ get; set; }
}
```

But i dont know how to work with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to deserialize an array of LocalhostTiming into one instance of it.
You need to deserialize the object to an array.

```
List<LocalhostTiming> jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LocalhostTiming>>(htmlCode);
```